# How to make JAWS announce updates in Eclipse SWT widgets?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jaws-screen-reader, aria-live

I'd like to have announced text updates in some lable, currently I'm trying with org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text(). And I'm trying that with JAWS(version 04.2023).

**I found [Snippet363](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet363.java)** It shows an example of something similar to ARIA-LIVE(in HTML) but for SWT, but unfortunatelly it **doesn't work for me**.

Also I tried to **change the Role** in a different way than in the Snippet363:

```
        liveLabel.getAccessible().addAccessibleControlListener(new AccessibleControlAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void getRole(AccessibleControlEvent e) {
                e.detail = ACC.ROLE_ALERT;
                called(e);
            }
        });
```

That didn't work as either.

There are no detailed informatin on how that should work. But here [the Java docs for the Accessible in SWT I found.](https://www.ibm.com/docs/it/rsar/9.5?topic=SS5JSH_9.5.0/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/accessibility/AccessibleAttributeListener.htm)

**So my questions are:**

1. Do I miss something from that Snippet363?
2. Do I need any additional setup/configs/props/or whatever to make it working?
3. Is there any other way to force JAWS to announce text from SWT?

Any help/advise on that much appreciated.